# Entity Framework Junction Table

Tags: entity-framework-4, edmx

I have a simple many-to-many relationship in my database:

```
Users --> UserRoles <-- Roles
```

When adding these to my EDMX file the junction table is being displayed and the relationships are not being shown.

Are there any special settings that might prevent the navigation settings from being displayed?

Comment: If `UserRoles` _only_ contains foreign keys (as db contraints) to Users and Roles, and nothing else, then EF will see it as a pure join table and not include it in the mapping as an entity of its own.

Comment: In our case this table currently contains some other values, so I'd expect the EDMX to show the table, but also for the navigation properties to be added for each of the FK's. My current issue is with the navigation properties not appearing.

Comment: Hmm, weird. The FKs are really db constraints?

Comment: Yep. Found the problem, have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case I have found my own answer. In our case we had set some security settings on the columns that prevented the mapping  (don't know how). Removed the security that wasn't needed then the navigation props appeared as expected.

HTH